# QT access violation on project reference

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to launch my QT application from another vcxproj. When the application gets executed stand-alone as an .exe, there are no issues. However, when the application gets references (by a .lib) I get an access violation in Qt5Widgetsd.dll. The project referencing the QT-project is however not a QT-project, so I needed to add the QT lib-references manually.

The QT-application gets invoked from the other thread by this code:
function call:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(Start);
```

Function itself:

```
void Start() 
{
    int argc = 1;
    char *argv[] = { (char*) "" };
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    qRegisterMetaType<Mat>("Mat");
    qRegisterMetaType<HANDLE>("HANDLE");
    MyQTProject::g_MyQTProject = new MyQTProject();
    a.exec();
}
```

The used .dll's when standalone: https://pastebin.com/TwQ0wrqa.

The used .dll's when referencing the QT-project: https://pastebin.com/UYGTUMM0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt is not designed to do that: `QApplication` must run in the main thread. While it usually works on Windows in spite of such abuse, it's not supported, not tested, and as you see: sometimes it breaks. Also, it's not cross platform.

You'll have to:

1. Prepare a static build of Qt.
2. Build your library using that copy of Qt.

The library must have no dependencies other than the VC runtime.

This is necessary because the invoking application also seems to be a Qt application; they seem to link to the same copy of Qt, and then you attempt to have two `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` objects in the same program. This will not work. Even if you have only one application object, there are other global Qt symbols that get initialized behind your back, and the library will try to initialize them after your main program had already done so. This will *not* work.

Comment: I used vcpkg to create static QT libraries, works now, thank you!